# Using Dapper and Entity Framework within the same transaction

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, dapper

Are there any issues/gotchas using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) and Entity Framework 6 in the same [database transaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbtransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) with SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction()){

    //EF
    var hoge = db.HogeTable.FirstOrDefault();
    hoge.Name = "fuga";
    db.SaveChanges();

    //Dapper
    // create query and params
    db.Database.Connection.Execute(query, params, tran.UnderlyingTransaction);
    tran.Commit();
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.